# Whats the difference between these two properties?

Tags: swift, swift2

What's the difference between these two??

```
var sharedContextA: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return CoreDataStackManager.sharedInstantce().managedObjectContext
}


var sharedContextB = {
    return CoreDataStackManager.sharedInstantce().managedObjectContext
}()
```

To clarify, I have seen:

```
var variable: Type {
    code
    return X
}
```

but I don't know the name of this or how it is different than the former:

```
var variable = {
    code
    return X
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sharedContextA` is a computed property. The value to be returned is computed each time the getter of the property is called.

`sharedContextB` uses a closure to assign a default value to the property. The closure is executed once during initialization of the type the property belongs to, afterwards the stored value is read directly.

Comment: Actually the closure of `sharedContextB` is executed directly with its creation and therefore is not lazily evaluated. For a lazy evaluation you have to use the `lazy` keyword in front of the variable.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the note. I update the answer

Comment: Try to add print() in both and call multiple times, you will get the difference.